# Select rows where column values are between a given range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to find and remove rows from DataFrame with values in a specific range, for example dates greater than '2017-03-02' and smaller than '2017-03-05'

```
import pandas as pd                                     

d_index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-06')     
d_values = pd.date_range('2017-03-01', '2017-03-06')    

s = pd.Series(d_values)                                 
s = s.rename('values')                                  

df = pd.DataFrame(s)                                    
df = df.set_index(d_index)                              

# remove rows with specific values in 'value' column
```

In example above I have d_values ordered from earliest to the latest date so in this case slicing dataframe by index could do the work. But I am looking for solution that would work also when d_values contain not ordered random date values. Is there any way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.Series.between` seems suited for this task.

```
df[~df['values'].between('2017-03-02', '2017-03-05', inclusive=False)]

               values
2018-01-01 2017-03-01
2018-01-02 2017-03-02
2018-01-05 2017-03-05
2018-01-06 2017-03-06
```

*Details*
`between` identifies all items *within* the range -

```
m = df['values'].between('2017-03-02', '2017-03-05', inclusive=False)
m

2018-01-01    False
2018-01-02    False
2018-01-03     True
2018-01-04     True
2018-01-05    False
2018-01-06    False
Freq: D, Name: values, dtype: bool
```

Use the mask to filter on `df` -

```
df = df[~m]
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, with the good ol' old logical OR -

```
df[~(df['values'].gt('2017-03-02') & df['values'].lt('2017-03-05'))]

               values
2018-01-01 2017-03-01
2018-01-02 2017-03-02
2018-01-05 2017-03-05
2018-01-06 2017-03-06
```

Note that both options work with datetime objects as well as string date columns (in which case, the comparison is lexicographic).

Comment: Nice solutions! I've posted an alternative method... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

first let's shuffle your DF:

```
In [65]: df = df.sample(frac=1)

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
               values
2018-01-03 2017-03-03
2018-01-04 2017-03-04
2018-01-01 2017-03-01
2018-01-06 2017-03-06
2018-01-05 2017-03-05
2018-01-02 2017-03-02
```

you can use [DataFrame.eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) method ([thanks @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for the correction!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366561/slice-dataframe-over-the-date-values/48366920?noredirect=1#comment83720440_48366920)):

```
In [70]: df[~df.eval("'2017-03-02' < values < '2017-03-05'")]
Out[70]:
               values
2018-01-01 2017-03-01
2018-01-06 2017-03-06
2018-01-05 2017-03-05
2018-01-02 2017-03-02
```

or [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [300]: df.query("not ('2017-03-02' < values < '2017-03-05')")
Out[300]:
               values
2018-01-01 2017-03-01
2018-01-06 2017-03-06
2018-01-05 2017-03-05
2018-01-02 2017-03-02
```

Comment: `query` seems to be your favourite ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, absolutely! I'm coming from the SQL word... ;-)

Comment: Actually, your condition is the opposite of what OP needs... they want to remove the rows you've selected... can it be inverted? Example: `df[~df.eval(...)]`